# web audio player - iOS next song & previous song buttons are not in control center

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext, mediasession

This is something I've researched off and on for literal years and have never been able to find the answer. I found the MediaSession api which works for populating song data but the next track and previous track action handlers don't make the next/ previous buttons appear in the iOS control center.

```
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
        title: '',
        artist: '',
        album: '',
        artwork: []
    });

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('stop', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekto', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('skipad', () => { /* Code excerpted. */ });
}
```

I found the AudioContext api which sounded promising because apple mentions it in their docs, but then the MediaSession metadata stops working and the next/ previous track buttons still don't appear.

```
context = new AudioContext();

audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');

const track = context.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

track.connect(context.destination);

audioElement.play()
```

Does anyone have experience with this? I attached some images that show what I'm trying to accomplish, the first image shows the controls that just using the MediaSession api gives me(skip forward/back 10 seconds), and the second image shows the controls that the Spotify web app is able to get(forward/back buttons).

For the life of me I cannot get the next/ previous track buttons to populate on iOS.

[image: MediaSession API]
[image: Spotify web app]

Comment: I'm having precisely the same problem. Indeed, I just checked Spotify's web app. They're the only one I've seen that actually manages to get the next / prev track buttons to populate. I'm curious if this is a hack on their part, or uses a deprecated api lost in old documentation. Thanks for identifying this on posting it!

Comment: I think Mohammads answer below fixed the issue in that you can't have all of the handlers, you must choose between seekbackward, seekforward and previoustrack, nexttrack. Its been 10 months since i last worked on this though so I would have to test again to be sure

Comment: I did try Mohammad's suggestion to no avail; both 1. only setting nexttrack / previoustrack and 2. nulling seekforward/seekbackward's handlers, in case there were some set by default. Neither worked. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3):

It seems it's a recent change in iOS and ipadOS that you cannot have both `seekbackward, seekforward` and `previoustrack, nexttrack` together. So you need to choose that you want to have next and previous track actions or seek backward and forward on iOS.

Comment: Can you point me to any references on this? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find the reference, Just try it with different versions and you will notice.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I did; no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by setting the action handlers once my `audio` element was playing using the `playing` event.
This was tested on my iPhone and iPad, both running iOS/iPadOS 17.3.1.

`skip` is a custom function.

```js
audio.addEventListener('playing', () => {
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', () => audio.play());
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', () => audio.pause());
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', () => {
    skip(-1);
    audio.play();
  });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', () => {
    skip(1);
    audio.play();
  });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekto', (details) => {
    if (details.seekTime) {
      audio.currentTime = details.seekTime;
    }
  });
});
```