# iOS 15 audio playlist problems

Tags: html, ios, html5-audio

I previously had HTML5 audio playlists working in iOS, even when the screen was locked. This was achieved using the solution suggested here: swapping out the the  src when the ended event was triggered.

[Can HTML5 in the browser play continuous audio on iOS lock screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462253/can-html5-in-the-browser-play-continuous-audio-on-ios-lock-screen)

Now on iOS15 this seems to have stopped working and so playlists reach the end of the first track and the next one never starts.

Has anyone experienced this too?  Anyone know a solution? This makes my website basically broken for people who want to listen to audio playlists while the phone is locked.

Comment: You've tried [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js), I'm not sure if it's right for you. But still take a look and comment if it works for you or not.

Comment: Did you get any solution yet? I am facing a same problem.

Comment: Got this issue after upgrading to IOS 15.4 on my IPad. Anyone found solution to deal with apple's idiosyncrasies?

Answer (score 1):

Met same problem.

It seems like safari on iOS 15 locked audio element when src changes, which won't happen on iOS 14 and before.

You can try to use `howler.js` to partially solve this problem. This library creates 5 or more audio elements when user interacts, but it will still encounter the same problem when pre-created audio elements is depleted in the background.

Comment: So your answer doesn't really fix the issue, it just remove the amount of problem ?

Comment: @Elikill58 yep...

Comment: I finally understood the problem after wasting several hours on IOS. Now waiting for the solution...